# Saving and loading data in Java

Tags: java, file, save, load

I was working on a note app as an exercise and can't seem to understand how to get a file to save/load. I might need a bit help. I have just been starting out with my note app, everything was somewhat easy to understand until I got to the save/load bit. Researched it for a few hours and still understand none. Please help me.

```
    public void save() {
    try (ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("note.data")))){
        stream.writeObject(data);
        System.out.println("Saved!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to print :(");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to do anything.

```
    public void load() {
    Path file = Paths.get("note.data");
    if (Files.exists(file)) {
        try (ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))){
            data = (Map<LocalDate, String>) stream.readObject();
            stream.readObject();
            System.out.println("Locked and Loaded!");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed!" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Neither does this code. Both don't report back to the system.

The following lines are the full class:

```
package sample.controller;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StickyNotes {

   @FXML
   private DatePicker picker;

   @FXML
   private TextArea notes;

   private Map<LocalDate, String> data = new HashMap<>();

   public void initialize() throws Exception {
        load();
        picker.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldDate, date) -> {
            notes.setText(data.getOrDefault(date, ""));
            });
        picker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    }

    public void updateNotes() {
        data.put(picker.getValue(), notes.getText());
    }

    public void exit() {
        save();
            System.out.println("Failed to print :(");
        Platform.exit();
    }
    public void save() {
        try (ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("note.data")))){
            stream.writeObject(data);
            System.out.println("Saved!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to print :(");
        }
    }

    public void load() {
        Path file = Paths.get("note.data");
        if (Files.exists(file)) {
            try (ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))){
                data = (Map<LocalDate, String>) stream.readObject();
                stream.readObject();
                System.out.println("Locked and Loaded!");
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Failed!" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... why are you trying to use Object streams? All your app does is store text based notes, yeah? You might want to take the time to review some [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) material at this time. Hint: BufferedReader and BufferedWriter are your friends.

Comment: Thank you! But what's the difference between Object streams and BufferedReader/Writer?